# Neo4jClient: specify Cypher parser version?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

Is there a way to specify the version of the Cypher parser in Neo4jClient on a per-query basis, as described [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-compatibility.html)?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this, but have raised an issue on the Neo4jClient bitbucket site: https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issue/155/ability-to-set-the-parser-version-on-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you update your Neo4jClient to the most recent (> 1.0.0.604) you will have access to the 'ParserVersion' method, which you use like:

```
client.Cypher
    .ParserVersion(1,9)
    .Start( new {n = All.Nodes} )
    .Return<object>("n")
```

Which creates the cypher:

```
CYPHER 1.9
START n = nodes(*)
RETURN n
```

If you use a version less than 1.9, you'll get the `CYPHER LEGACY` start instead.